# Pass parameter name to a function in python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, pipeline

Thank you for your time reading this question.

I want to use an existing function through a PIPELINE. I want to give the name of the parameter into that pipeline as well as its value.

How can I pass the name of the parameter into a that function?

Like:

```
parm_name = "age"
value  = 33
foo (parm_name=value)
```

instead we do:

```
params = {'age': [11, 23, 33]}
pipeline(foo, params)
```

So, I have to define my pipeline function. But I don't know how to pass parameter names inside a string.

Thank you dear. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this

```
parm_name = "age"
value  = 33
d = {param_name: value}
foo(**d)
```

We can create dictionary with param nam as strings and there value and when we call **d its called unpacking so this will transform to param_name=value while calling the function.

Comment: Can you upvote  and accept the answer if you like it ?